# How to run commands on all submodules recursively, starting with the deepest submodules and working upward?

Tags: windows, git, command-line-arguments, git-submodules

## Issue

I have repositories several levels deep, and I want to commit to all of them, starting with the deepest repositories then working upwards.

E.g.

```
- Main
  - A
    - A1
    - A2
  - B
    - B2
    - B3
```

## What I have Tried

I have tried to `git submodule foreach --recursive`, but apparently this goes **top-down**, instead of **bottom-up**.

Example command:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive "git checkout main && git add --all && git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m \"My Commit Message\""
```

## Problem

The problem with above is that if there are changes to `A1` & `A2`, it will fail at `A` with this message:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   A1 (modified content)
        modified:   A2 (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for Path/To/A
.
```

## Question

How do I recursively run commands on all *submodules* from the **bottom-up**?